# Is it impossible to put AutoCompeleteBox inside of DataForm?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I tried to use autocompletebox inside of dataform instead of TextBox. but I cannot see instance name of autocompletebox in the class file.

BTW, If I put autocompletebox outside of dataform, I can see instance name of autocompletebox, "acbEmpName".

So, my question is that Is it impossible to put autocompletebox inside of dataform?
If so, How to use autocompletebox inside of dataform?

I am using silverlight3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AutoCompleteBox should work well with DataForm, with the only exception being that AutoCompleteBox does not conform to the "IsReadOnly" convention that some of the other controls do, so in read-only mode your experience visually might be a little less than ideal.

Is it possible that this is a sizing issue? Could you try putting the AutoCompleteBox control inside of a StackPanel, or providing a specific size - height 40 width 120, or something like that, to see if it appears better?

Answer (score 0):

you can find a sample here
http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/working-with-dataform/